# Invoking a pipeline from another pipeline using scripted jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins

I am using the following snippet to invoke a pipeline1 from pipeline2 both the pipelines have their own Jenkins file in their respective git repo

```
stage
{
  build job:'../pipeline1Repo/master',parameters:[[$class:'StringParameterValue',name:'USER', value:'user'],[$class:'StringParameterValue',name:'PASSWORD', value:'password']],wait:true
}
```

The repo location in git for pipelines are:

```
pipeline1 repo - https://github.company-domain.com/main/pipeline1-repo
pipeline2 repo - https://github.company-domain.com/main/pipeline2-repo
```

when I am running the job I am getting following error:

> build
>   job:'../pipeline1Repo/master',parameters:[[$class:'StringParameterValue',name:'USER',
>   value:'user'],[$class:'StringParameterValue',name:'PASSWORD',
>   value:'password']],wait:true

Note- I don't have the access to check the installed plugins I am assuming is this can be due to pipeline plugin is not installed and if so is there another way to do so without using a plugin

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you get? You should be told what is causing the problem there, could you go to console log of that specific build you are running and copy the right error?

Comment: That is the error I am getting and one more thing is that both pipeline uses same jenkins node and uses same docker image

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the plugin as I didn't have the admin access I could not check the plugin was there or not.
After installing the pipeline plugin it got resolved